# RLS in SSRS 2017

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I've a SSRS report which is contains the column **CreatedBy** and I need use this column to enable row level security. The requirement is like below.

```
Manager CreatedBY 
A       user1
A       user2
B       user3
B       user4
B       user5
```

so when manager A logs in, he should see all the records created by user1 and user2 so does manager B can see all the records created user3,user4 and user5.

will this below query sufficient to achieve the same or need to adjust anything?

```
select * from table
where createdby IN '@UserID'
```

@UserID - I will create this parameter in SSRS.

thanks for the support.

Regards,
Viresh

Answer (score 0):

Use `=`:

```
select *
from table
where createdby = @UserID;
```

You shouldn't need single quotes around the value if you pass the value in as a *parameter*.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the @UserID parameter will contain. Will it be the manager's ID or a list of the UserIDs?

If it contains the ManagerID (e.g. `A`) then you could just do

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE Manager = @UserID
```

If @UserID is a list of values passed in from the report (a multi-value report paramter) then you can do something like

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CreatedBY IN (@UserID)
```

If you use the 2nd method, be aware that this will only work if the dataset query is just a SQL statement or script, it will not work (without extra work) if you are calling a stored proc directly in the dataset query. SSRS will take the list of vaules and inject them so if you passed in a list of `User1` and `User2` the final query that is passed to SQL Server would effectively be

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CreatedBY IN('User1', 'User2')
```

Comment: Hi, In my case the records will be created by the users and I don't want to give the access to those users. I need to allow their respective managers to see the data created by all users whom they report.

Suppose there are 5 users and first 3 users reports manager1 and next 2 users report to manger2. When manager1 access the report, he should see all the records created by 3 users and manager2 can see the records created by other 2 users.

thanks for your suggestions